# Is there something similar to stringByAppendingPathComponent in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to compose a file path in Android, for example:

```
String filepath = getFilesDir() + "/" + "1.txt";
```

because the value of method `getFilesDir()` will not contain a `/` at the end, so I must add a `/` manually.

Is this normal? Is there something like `[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]`(an Objective-C method which will add `/` automatically) in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the constructor of `File` that takes two parameters. The first is the directory, the file returned by `getFilesDir()` in your case, , the second is the name of the file:

```
 String filepath = new File(getFilesDir(), "1.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use operation of string concatenation, you produce some scratch string objects for each step. 
Thats why it is recomedly to use such objects as StringBuffer(thread safe) or StringBuilder(trhead not safe).

```
String filepath = new StringBuilder(getFilesDir()).append("/").append("1.txt");
```